# org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: cannot open git-upload-pack

Tags: java, git, github, jgit, transport

I am trying to use Jgit for getting a clone from remote repository. The code is as follows:

```
File file = new File(localPath);
    CloneCommand cloneCmd = git.cloneRepository();
    try {
        cloneCmd.setURI(remotePath).setDirectory(file).call();
    } catch (GitAPIException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But, I am getting org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: cannot open git-upload-pack. What is the solution for this error?

Comment: `git` should be `Git`. Aside from that, your code should be working fine.

Comment: Can you post the `remotePath` value?

Comment: remotePath = "https://stash.gto.intranet.db.com:8081//projects//PARAGON//repos//paragongit//browse";

Comment: You don't have a protocol?

Comment: what type of protocol?

Comment: my remote_path is remotePath = "https://username%40db.com@stash.gto.intranet.db.com:8081/scm/paragon/paragongit.git";